# KnockoutJS - when to use parentheses with observable

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to KnockoutJS and have observed in some of the examples on the main site, http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html , that sometimes when accessing observables, parentheses are used, and sometimes they aren't.

Could someone explain to me in which instances parentheses are appropriate or not when accessing observables (and observableArrays)?

Snippet of code with both parentheses and no-parentheses for accessing same observable:

```
self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
    return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, 
    phones:ko.observableArray(contact.phones) };
}));
// .... 
self.removePhone = function(phone) {
    $.each(self.contacts(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })
};

self.save = function() {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses in ko we usually use for evaluating `observable/observableArray` .

**Example :**

```
 self.value1 = ko.observable(2);
 self.value2 = 2 ;
```

**with Parentheses:**

```
self.value1() gives you 2 
self.value1 gives you function(){//blah blah} which actually denotes its observable
```

***without Parentheses:***

```
self.value2() gives undefined i.e not a function 
self.value2   gives you 2
```

In short observables value can only be accessed using parentheses . If you directly assign `self.value2=2` means its just like `var s=2` so there is no point trying to access value of a variable as `s()` we can get simply using `s`

**In Your scenarios :**

**Case 1:**

Here inside return if they are accessing value via `contact.firstName` means `firstName` is not observable

```
self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
    return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, 
    phones:ko.observableArray(contact.phones) };
}));
```

**case 2:**

Here `self.contacts` is not a plain array its observable array to access its content & to loop we use `()` there

```
self.removePhone = function(phone) {
    $.each(self.contacts(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })
};
```

**case 3:**

Inside `ko.toJS` even it is `self.contacts` or `self.contacts()` both are fine (refer above)

```
self.save = function() {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
};
```

You can check yourself in this fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/168qgoon/)** if you change something the preview data remains static which just says two way binding not there (not observable)

Answer (score 1):

In Knockout parentheses are used when you need to evaluate an observable. Observables are functions so you need to call the function to get the value. So if you have `self.contacts = ko.observable()` to get the value of this you would use `self.contacts()`. To set the value you use `self.contacts(2)`.

You need to declare an observable if you want knockout to know when the value changes such as:

- the data is changed in javascript and the view should be updated
- a field or fields in the view (such as an input field) that the value is attached to changes

The Knockout documentation explains a bit about observables: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html